# IIS Limit access to file + Basic Authentication

Tags: security, iis, web-config, iis-8.5

I have a simple internal site using IIS 8.5 Basic Authentication.
In one specific html file I want to restrict even further to some users/roles.

UPDATE: This is my Web.config, I can still access the inhouse.html file in a browser with my Windows (LDAP) account. I want to block all users to access this. Then to only allow a few users.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>

<location path="inhouse.html">
   <system.web>
       <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />

       </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<location path="inhouse.html">
   <system.web>
       <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
          --add the users you want here.
       </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

It depends on the rest of your web.config as to whether system.webserver or system.web applies.

Comment: I'm trying this. Can access with my account but this should block all?

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    </system.web>
 
 <location path="inhouse.html">
    <system.web>
     <authorization>
     <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
     
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>

</configuration>

Comment: You would need a `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in there (within system.web) to be in the correct mode.